# Why doesn't the printer appear in the list on Sierra OSx?

Tags: macos, drivers, printing, printer, network-printer

I have a computer at office that I recently upgraded to sierra.

I am trying to add a Xerox office printer, but when I try to choose the Printer Software (when adding the printer), I have a very short list, and no Xerox printers there!

Choosing "Auto Select" in the Printer Add dialog box (under IP) doesn't work well with the printer (it chooses Generic PostScript Printer).

Any ideas why my printer doesn't appear in the list, and why is the list so short to begin with?

I tried finding drivers for the Xerox printer here:

http://www.support.xerox.com/support/global-printer-driver/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=macos1012

but I get no results.

I also checked the list of supported printers by Sierra, here

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201465

and it is there:

WC 7556 *   3.81.1  P

Answer (score 0):

OSX ships with a generic PostScript driver that is suitable for your printer. All you need is the PPD file for the printer. This is a text file that tells the driver what features the printer supports, and how to activate them.

Download the [PPD file](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-7545-7556/file-download/enus.html?operatingSystem=win81&fileLanguage=en&&associatedProduct=XRIP_WC7525_base&contentId=132125&from=downloads&viewArchived=false) and unzip it. Then copy XeroxWorkCentre7556.ppd to /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources. Now Add the printer. When asked for the model, browse to the PPD and finish the installation.